# Spring security autoredirecting to login page not showing public homepage

Tags: java, spring-security

I have a problem with Spring Security configuration in Java based tomcat application. I would like a user to access my homepage without a need to login, but sometimes Spring redirects me to login page instead of showing me my index page (which is allowed in the configuration to be accessed without authorization). It IS actually accessible without logging in if I click to go to the homepage, but anyways shows me sometimes this login page.

I've already tried to search for a solution and to tinker with the configuration, but it doesn't seem to provide any help.

I would like homepage to be always accessible without login, and without redirecting to the login page. I would offer a user link to login page from my homepage, but not whenever a user enters an URL to my homepage.

````
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement()
                .invalidSessionUrl("/login")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/",
                        "/fonts/**",
                        "/i18n/**",
                        "/js/**",
                        "/css/**",
                        "/images/**",
                        "/error",
                        "/403",
                        "/rules",
                        "/check-username",
                        "/check-mail",
                        "/users",
                        "/users/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/mail").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/login*",
                        "/forgot",
                        "/reset",
                        "/register-success",
                        "/registration_confirm",
                        "/register",
                        "/logout",
                        "/forgotSuccess",
                        "/changePassword",
                        "/updatePasswordSuccess")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/resetPassword*", "/savePassword*", "/updatePassword*")
                .hasAuthority("CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").deleteCookies("auth_code", "JSESSIONID").invalidateHttpSession(true).clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .rememberMe().key("mysecretkey").rememberMeCookieName("remember-me").tokenValiditySeconds(24 * 60 * 60).rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenRepository(tokenRepository())
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(customAccessDeniedHandler);
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
 @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
      .ignoring()
         .antMatchers("/resources/**"); // #3
  }
```

[for more details](https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/)